# Undefined function inside map in angular 2

Tags: angular

I’m working in angular2, I define in a service a function getAccountName, and in the same component I use it in extractArrayData function, like this:

```
private extractArrayData(response: Response): Analysis[] {
 …
      analysisList.map(analysis => {
        if (analysis.userAccess >= Access.UPDATE && !analysis.group) {
          this.getAccountName(analysis.accountId)
          .flatMap(name => {
              analysis.group = name;
              return this.updateAnalysis(analysis);
            })
            .subscribe((analysisUp) => console.log('analysis group from ' + analysisUp.id + ' updated'));
        }
      });
      return analysisList;
    }


public getAccountName(accountId: number): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl + 'api/account/name' + '/' + accountId)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

But I get the error message: 
TypeError: _this.getAccountName is not a function

Can anyone explain this error for me

Comment: Where and how do you call `extractArrayData`?

Comment: public getUser(userId: number): Observable<Analysis[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.Api + '/user/' + userId)
      .map(this.extractArrayData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

Comment: Try `.map(this.extractArrayData.bind(this)) `

Comment: did u inject your service into the component's constructor ?

Comment: @yurzui thank you your solution solve my issue, can you juste explain to me more why i have this problem??

Comment: In JavaScript, this is a variable that’s set when a function is called. When you write `this.extractArrayData` you just pass function reference to `map` operator and it will be called inside rxjs See also http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

Comment: okay , thank you so much